# Apex Triggered upon Viewing a Record via Invisible Aura Component Bundle

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

This project is essentially doing an auto-deduplication function on cases created via inbound emails within a certain time frame based on having the same subject line (including the RE:'s from replies within that time frame). It was started by a consultant then i took the project over. It is using a lightning component to trigger an apex callout, however when i moved all the change set items to my 2nd sandbox instance i am unable to have the action triggered by opening(clicking on and viewing) a case.

Component:

```
<aura:component description="akaCaseListener" extends="c:akaBaseLib" controller="akaCaseListenerController" implements="force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">
    <aura:attribute name="isActive" access="public" default="true" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

Controller:

```
({
    doInit:function (component, event, helper) {
        if(component.get('v.isActive') === true) {
            helper.callCreateDuplicateCaseEmail(component, helper);
        }
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    callCreateDuplicateCaseEmail:function (component, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.createDuplicateCaseEmail');
        action.setParams({'recordId': component.get('v.recordId')});
        helper.callApex(component, action, null, null);
   }
})
```

Design:

```
<design:component label="akaCRM Case Listener">
    <design:attribute name="isActive" label="Active?" description="When this is set to true, the component will be active" />
    <sfdc:objects>
        <sfdc:object>Case</sfdc:object>
    </sfdc:objects>
</design:component>
```

Looking for any information regarding what is preventing this component from firing off the other code

Comment: Is the isactive attribute set to true?

Comment: Yes, it is set to true, i checked to be sure.